# Why does iphoto only open 4 images in the external editor?

Tags: photos.app

I am using Photoshop as the external editor, but when I select a series of photos (more than 4) within iPhoto and choose "open in external editor" only the first four of the selected open. It's pretty annoying because I don't want to have to keep going back and forth between the programs to see what i have open in Photoshop. I just want to select (holding control and selecting) different images to then edit outside of the program.

Is this a setting i can adjust? What possible reason would there be for this limitation?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question, please?

Comment: @ruddfawcett I tried to elaborate, but I thought my question was pretty clear. have you tried it yourself and not encountered that problem?

Comment: Ah.. I didn't realize that the beginning if the description carried over from the question title.  I have never had this problem.  Have you tried switching the editor to see if you get the same problem?

Comment: No Photoshop is the only image editor I have on my machine. I also just upgraded iphoto to the latest version hoping that it would have fixed it, but alas no. I am basically using iPhoto for image management, and Photoshop for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is to protect against User error - the kind of thing that happens when an inexperienced user doesn't realise that s/he has every photo in their Library selected and then opts to send to the external editor.

No, there is no setting to adjust. Nor have I ever found a way to hack the limitation.

Comment: That makes sense. I would hate to accidentally open 2000 images. I just wish there was an option to edit that number.